# Swift playground image doesn't show what it should

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

I got the following code that I run in XCode playground:

```
let initalFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:10,height:10)
let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))

myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3);
myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15
myLabel.text = "Wow"

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = initalFrame
let startCol = UIColor(hue: 0.580555, saturation: 0.31, brightness: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
let endCol = UIColor(hue: 0.58333, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.62, alpha: 1.0)
gradient.colors = [startCol, endCol]
myLabel.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
myLabel.textAlignment = .Center
```

But I have faced the following issues:

1. The background exceed the rounded rect.
2. The gradient doesn't show.

An image here:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UAa1.png)
How to fix my problems? Thanks for any hints. Does anyone look at this question!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a playground, play around with `myLabel.clipSubviews`, `myLabel.layer.masksToBounds` and the index at which you put the gradient layer